# Speed Performance In Recursive SQL Requests

Tags: sql, caching, recursion

I have so category and this categories have unlimited sub category.
In Database Table, Fields are ID, UpperID and Title.

If I call a category and its subcategory in DataTable with recursive method in program(ASP.NET project)
performance is very bad.
And many user will use this application so everything goes bad.
Maybe All categories Fill to A Cache object and then we musnt go to Database.
But category count is 15000 or 20000.
So I think isn't a good method.

What can I do for fast performance?
Are you give me any suggestion?

Comment: give us your sql-stmt :)

Comment: Indeed share your query, it might be possible to create a recursive query. Also tell us what kind of DMBS you're using?

Comment: You need to do the math - how many users?  How big are category objects in memory?  How much memory do you have available?  How big is this bottleneck?  Are you using a per-user threading model?  If so, is there a way to build a persistent cache that is single-instance, perhaps by building a companion service on the same machine and connecting to it via a fast interprocess communication layer?

Comment: @mike: the schema of category is pretty clear, as he stated it in the question: `ID, UpperID, Title`.

Comment: I'm not sure that necessarily tells you how the thing behaves in memory, but I guess it depends on what you're caching, so fair enough.  Regardless, that's the smallest piece of the puzzle.  If you have 100,000,000 users, it probably doesn't matter how small your objects are, you're going to have problems if you cache one instance of every value for every user.

Comment: @mike: that would be wrong way. i suggest something like the repository-pattern. to work efficiantly it requires that categories are not connected to users (eg. you categorize users), but that there might be n consumers of your repository ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks All,

I find my solution with Common Table Expressions(CTE) fifty- fifty.
Its allow fast recursive queries.

```
WITH CatCTE(OID, Name, ParentID) 
AS 
( 
   SELECT OID, Name, ParentID FROM Work.dbo.eaCategory
   WHERE OID = 0   
       UNION ALL 
   SELECT C.OID, C.Name, C.ParentID FROM Work.dbo.eaCategory  C JOIN CatCTE as CTE ON C.ParentID= CTE.OID
) 
SELECT * FROM CatCTE
```

Answer (score 1):

`caching` or other in-memory-persistance is by far better than doing this on a relational system :) ... hey... it's oop!

just my 2 cents!

eg.

```
var categories = /* method for domain-objects*/.ToDictionary(category => category.ID);
foreach (var category in categories.Values)
{
    if (!category.ParentCategoryID.HasValue)
    {
        continue;
    }
    Category parentCategory;
    if (categories.TryGetValue(category.ParentCategoryID.Value, out parentCategory))
    {
        parentCategory.AddSubCategory(category);
    }
}
```

et voila ... your tree is ready to go!

**edit:**
do you *exactly know where* your performance bottle-neck is?...

to give you some ideas, eg:

- loading from database
- building up the structure
- querying the structure

loading from database:
then you should load it once and be sure to have some changetracking/notifying to get changes (if made) or optimize your query!

building up the structure:
the way i create the tree (traversal part) is the wastest you can do with a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

querying the structure:
the structure i've used in my example is faster than `List<T>`. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses an index over the keys - so you may use `int` for the keys (IDs)

**edit:**

> So you use DataTable to fix the
>   problem. Now you've got 2 problems: me
>   and DataTable

what do you have right now? where are you starting from? can you determine where your mudhole is? give us code!

Comment: Thanks, but my code like as your code.
I have 20000 category record and many user.
So my problem is speed.
I look for best performance.